# How to compute sine values somewhere, and then move then into XMM0 in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, sse

I was doing the integration task with FPU before, now I'm struggling with SSE.

My main problem is when I was using FPU stack, there was the `fsin` function, which could be used on the number, which is at the top of the stack (st0).

Now I want to calculate the sine of my all four numbers in `XMM0`, or calculate it somewhere else and move into `XMM0`. I'm using the AT&T syntax.

I think the second idea is actually possible, but I don't know how :)

Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: sinus? I don't think that means what you think it does (and it's not a verb).

Comment: fsin doesn't sinus the value on top of the stack?

Comment: It's called 'sine' in English.

Comment: This answer is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1845204/1256624 (Summary, SSE doesn't appear to provide a native `sin` instruction). Also, this page looks like it might help: http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/

Comment: @dbaupp I know that SSE doesn't provie it, but maybe you know how to insert values from fpu stack into xmm0?

Comment: Google turns up [this](http://www.asmcommunity.net/board/index.php?topic=30778.0). (The second link I provided up above appears to have implementations of `sin`/`cos`/etc in SSE; these may even be more performant, due to vectorization and SSE generally being better etc.)

Comment: The fsin (etc) instructions were pretty bad anyway. Only useful when optimizing for size - and in that case you probably won't be using SSE. This may be useful: http://devmaster.net/forums/topic/4648-fast-and-accurate-sinecosine/  (add reduction if you're outside the range)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options:

1. Use and existing library that computes `sin` on SSE vectors.
2. Write your own vector `sin` function using SSE.
3. Store the vector to memory, use `fsin` to compute the sine of each element, and load the results.  Assuming that your stack is 16-byte aligned and has 16-bytes of space, something like this:

   ```
      movaps  %xmm0, (%rsp)
      mov     $3,     %rcx
   0: flds   (%rsp,%rcx,4)
      fsin
      fstps  (%rsp,%rcx,4)
      sub     $1,     %rcx
      jns     0b
   ```

(1) is almost certainly your best bet performance-wise, and is also the easiest.  If you have significant experience writing vector code and know *a priori* that the arguments fall into some range, you may be able to get better performance with (2).  Using `fsin` will work, but it's ugly and slow and not particularly accurate, if that matters.